# File input to a particular field

Tags: bash

I have an empty file called choice.txt with four headings.

```
choice1      choice2        choice3       choice4
```

I would like to input some info to specific fields. For example,

```
echo $total >> (field3) choice.txt
```

I know taking info from specific fields is easy but i cant find any tutorials on this way

Comment: how are the fields separated? tabs or spaces?

Comment: they are seperated with tabs

Comment: ok, and are you only appending to that file or do you need to update existing records?

Comment: yes i only want to append to the file. All four fields will be empty to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "" "" "$total" "" >> choice.txt
```

This will add four fields separated with tabs, and a newline character to your file, using `$total` as the third field and leaving the other fields empty.

You can pretty-print your tab-delimited file like this:

```
column -t -s $'\t' choice.txt
```

Comment: ah yes, very good. I was thinking of trying something like this but didn't know how to go about it. Thank you

Comment: @rog: You are welcome. Note on pretty-printing added. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.